# How to get list of dates between From Date and To Date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, php

I have a table `` Emp_UnAvailablity_ID`, `PersonID`, `Is_UnAvailable`, `From_Date`, `To_Date` FROM `emp_unavailablity ``. I want to get list of all dates between `From_Date` and `To_Date`. I have tried this query `SELECT date(From_Date) AS F, DATEDIFF(date(To_Date), date(From_Date)) AS D FROM emp_unavailablity` its output is in the attached image [image: Query Output]

Here is my table data [image: Table Data]

I have tried some php code to get list of dates but not worked for me.

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;
    $sql = " 
        SELECT date(From_Date) AS F, DATEDIFF(date(To_Date), date(From_Date)) AS D FROM emp_unavailablity ";
    $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
    $dataReader = $command->queryAll();

    $newValues = array();
    foreach($dataReader as $key => $value) 
    {
        $newValues[$key] = $value;
        if($key == 'F') 
        {
            for ($i=0; $i < $key['D']; $i++) { 
                $xx = $key['F'] + $i;     //f + i
                $newValues = $xx;
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($newValues);
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the accepted answer on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query), you can adapt it to fit your requirements:

```
select * 
from emp_unavailablity, 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) datelist from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) as v
where datelist>from_date and datelist <to_date;
```

Basically we build an inline view with a list of all dates for the next few thousand years, and use that as a list to `select` from.

Sample SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f29a79/3).